# Javascript sub methods / namespacing with constructor functions

Tags: javascript, object-literal

**I cannot thank you enough for your time and help!** I've searched for almost 2 days and cannot find my exact answer. To begin:

I've always used object literal notation to create my objects. However, I've recently come across a situation where I need to create multiple instances of the same object. I believe what I'm attempting to create are "constructor functions":

I need to have the ability to create multiple "Window" objects:

```
var window1 = new Window();
var window2 = new Window();
var window3 = new Window();
```

I want the ability to be able to organize methods as such:

```
window1.errorMessage.show();
window2.errorMessage.hide();
window3.errorMessage.hide();
```

Instead of something like:

```
window1.showErrorMessage();
window2.hideErrorMessage();
window3.hideErrorMessage();
```

**An example of how I would build my window object in literal notation:**

```
var Window = {
    id: null,
    
    init : function(id) {
        this.id = id;
    },

    errorMessage : {
        show : function(message) {
            // jquery that will simply take the id of this window,
            //  find the errorMessage html element within the window,
            //  insert the "message" and show it.
        },
    
        hide : function() {
            // jquery that will simply take the id of this window,
            //  find the errorMessage html element within this window and hide it.
        }
    }
}
```

**An example of how I would attempt to build my window object using constructor functions and prototyping:**

```
function Window(id) {
    this.id = id;

    this.errorMessage = function() {}
}

Window.prototype.errorMessage = function() {}

Window.errorMessage.prototype.show = function(message) {
    // jquery that will simply take the id of this window,
    //  find the errorMessage html element within the window,
    //  insert the "message" and show it.
}

Window.errorMessage.prototype.hide = function() {
    // jquery that will simply take the id of this window,
    //  find the errorMessage html element within this window and hide it.
}
```

**When I attempt to execute the following code:**

```
var window1 = new Window();

window1.errorMessage.show('An error message');
```

(Ultimately I would like to call it using:)

```
this.errorMessage.show('An error message');
```

I receive the following console errors from Firefox:

- TypeError: Window.errorMessage is undefined
- TypeError: Window.errorMessage.show is not a function

**Thank so much for you help. I appreciate it.**

Comment: Just as a suggestion, don't use `Window` - it's already an interface: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: You are assigning the property `errorMessage` to `Window.prototype`, but then are trying to access `Window.errorMessage`, which does not exist.

Comment: Oh, I definitely won't use "Window" in the end. I was just attempting to simplify what I'm attempting to achieve. But thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would still declare your methods on the function's prototype like you attempted, but you'll have to declare `show` and `hide` methods on a new `ErrorMessage` type. I think something like this is the best and most efficient (because instances of `ErrorMessage` will all share the same `show` and `hide` methods) thing to do (if I understand your needs correctly).

```
function Window(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.errorMessage = new ErrorMessage();
}

function ErrorMessage() { }
ErrorMessage.prototype.show = function() {}
ErrorMessage.prototype.hide = function() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to use `prototype` if you're doing inheritance. Since you're not doing inheritance forget about `prototype` for now.

Each `Window` has an instance of `ErrorMessage`. So I would write it like:

```
function Window(id) {
  this.id = id;
  this.errorMessage = new ErrorMessage();
}
function ErrorMessage() {
   this.show = function () {};
   this.hide = function () {};
}
var window1 = new Window();
window1.errorMessage.show();
```

Comment: `prototype` is not just for inheritance. It can be used exactly how the OP is trying to, just with some modification. There's nothing wrong with using it to set properties to be shared by all instances. Although I definitely like your solution...except it creates a new `ErrorMessage` for each instance, which could be avoided by sharing.

Comment: It sounds to me like he'll want a different error message for each window, so creating a new instance for each one is the right thing.

Comment: @Frits Like Ian said, there are other good reasons to declare methods on the prototype. Declaring methods as properties of the prototype is much more performant than creating a new method every time an object is instantiated.

Comment: @TrevorDixon It does *sound* like that, but who knows. Notice how the `show` and `hide` methods seem to be **generic** methods for showing and hiding the error message itself. I don't see how these need to be generated for each instance, without more info from the OP.

Comment: Hi all, thanks so much for the quick responses! I updated the code a bit to hopefully illustrate how these methods will be used. I believe I am attempting to create generic functions, as @Ian said, and as is why I thought of prototyping as the solution.